# sequence report Adobe Premiere CC

Tags: premiere, adobe

Avid has something called sequence report that gives you details such as the number of clips in a sequence among other stats. I was wondering if any of you were aware of a similar function in Premiere that would show some stats of the sequence (e.g. number of clips)?

Comment: The only thing I know of is the 'Properties' Display available from the context-menu of a sequence (right-click on the sequence in the project panel). This however will only show you the sequence's resolution, framerate and current duration ...